# Adding a view all with custom post type in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create something like our menu section in http://www.naijacanteen.com. I have created that section successfully, however I want to only display six item and have a view all link. Any idea how I can do that? Here is my code:

```
<?php 
if(has_post_thumbnail())
    the_post_thumbnail();
?>
</div>
<h3>
    <?php the_title();?></h3>
<p>
    <?php  the_content();?></p>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For create you have to loop through all post.Its better to use shortcode or template to make it flexible.I have always use a shortcode.

**How to create short code**

You have to open you functions.php and add below code

```
function add_resturant_menu(){

    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'resturant_menu_item', 'posts_per_page' => 6 );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

     if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
     while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
    echo "<h2>".the_title()."</h2>";
    echo "<div class='entry-content'>";
    the_content(); 
    echo "</div>";
    wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
    return;
}

add_shortcode('add_resturant_menu','add_resturant_menu');
```

**How to use in PHP file:**

It simple to add code inside the php file using

```
<?php do_shortcode('[add_resturant_menu]'); ?>
```

**How  to use in WYISWYG editor:**

add line code into editor.

```
['add_resturant_menu']
```